# 1. How to open one activity fragment from another activity fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Is this possible to open fragment from another activity fragment. If yes how. I have tried to solve it through fragment transaction method but it's not working.

I have tried this example but i am not using container in my code due to this it's not working

```
   Fragment mFragment = null;
mFragment = new MainFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

But i want do fragment transaction without container.

Comment: what problem you're facing

Comment: Can you please post the code used on trials ?

Comment: @AliAhmed   i have written my problem below in answer section check it.

Comment: Have you tried using an Activity to swap the fragments? Try passing your Activity through your first fragment's constructor then do activity.getSupportFragmentManager() and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to replace a fragment which is inside activity-A from activity-B?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to display a `Fragment`, you must have a container in your view. Generally, it's a `FrameLayout`. If your `Fragment` does not contain any UI, you can use [this add() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))